# How to use Scrapy sitemap spider on sites with text sitemaps?

Tags: python, scrapy, sitemap

I tried using a generic Scrapy.spider to follow links, but it didn't work - so I hit upon the idea of simplifying the process by accessing the `sitemap.txt` instead, but that didn't work either!

I wrote a simple example (to help me understand the algorithm) of a spider to follow the sitemap specified on my site: `https://legion-216909.appspot.com/sitemap.txt` It is meant to navigate the URLs specified on the sitemap, print them out to screen and output the results into a `links.txt` file. The code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import SitemapSpider

class MySpider(SitemapSpider):
    name = "spyder_PAGE"
    sitemap_urls = ['https://legion-216909.appspot.com/sitemap.txt']

    def parse(self, response):
        print(response.url)
        return response.url
```

I ran the above spider as `Scrapy crawl spyder_PAGE > links.txt` but that returned an empty text file. I have gone through the Scrapy docs multiple times, but there is something missing. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`SitemapSpider` is expecting an XML sitemap format, causing the spider to exit with this error:

`[scrapy.spiders.sitemap] WARNING: Ignoring invalid sitemap: <200 https://legion-216909.appspot.com/sitemap.txt>`

Since your `sitemap.txt` file is just a simple list or URLs, it would be easier to just split them with a string method.

For example:

```
from scrapy import Spider, Request

class MySpider(Spider):
    name = "spyder_PAGE"
    start_urls = ['https://legion-216909.appspot.com/sitemap.txt']

    def parse(self, response):
        links = response.text.split('\n')
        for link in links:
            # yield a request to get this link
            print(link)

# https://legion-216909.appspot.com/index.html
# https://legion-216909.appspot.com/content.htm
# https://legion-216909.appspot.com/Dataset/module_4_literature/Unit_1/.DS_Store
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to override `_parse_sitemap(self, response)` from `SitemapSpider` with the following:

```
from scrapy import Request
from scrapy.spiders import SitemapSpider

class MySpider(SitemapSpider):
   sitemap_urls = [...]
   sitemap_rules = [...]
   def _parse_sitemap(self, response):
        # yield a request for each url in the txt file that matches your filters
        urls = response.text.splitlines()
        it = self.sitemap_filter(urls)
        for loc in it:
            for r, c in self._cbs:
                if r.search(loc):
                    yield Request(loc, callback=c)
                    break
```

Comment: This did it for me. I'm dealing with a sitemap-index.xml which points to a bunch of txt files. I kept the existing functionality, and tacked on an additional step as a sort of fallback. 
nextreqs = list(super()._parse_sitemap(response))
if not nextreqs:
  # do txt fallback